# Calculate total price in a view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am a newbie to elixir and what I'm trying to do is calculate the total price of items in the user's cart and display it in the cart page. I wrote a function which is a mix of functions I found on the internet. I would appreciate any help!

Here is my index.html.eex for shopping cart

```
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
    <%= if @books do %>
      <ul>
        <%= for book <- @books do %>
          <li>
            <%= book.title %>: £<%= book.original_price %>
            <%= link "X", to: Routes.cart_path(@conn, :delete, book_slug: book.slug), method: :delete %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <p>No books in your cart</p>
    <% end %>
<%= total_price(@books) %>
```

And the cart_view

```
  def total_price(books) do
    shipping = 5.99

    price_with_shipping =
      Enum.reduce(books, fn book, acc ->
        %{total_amount: book.original_price + acc.total_amount + shipping}
      end)
      |> Map.get(:total_amount)

    text = "Total amount: #{price_with_shipping}"
  end
```

In the end, it only displays this part - "Total amount: " without the calculated price with shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you can see “Total amount: ” part in the view, the view is fine.
2. `<%= total_price(@books) %>` should be **inside** `if` clause.
3. You want to calculate a total, which is a number, not a map. So reduce the number.

That said, the below should work.

```elixir
def total_price(books) do
  shipping = 5.99

  price_with_shipping =
    Enum.reduce(books, 0, fn %{original_price: price}, acc ->
      price + acc + shipping
    end)

  "Total amount: #{price_with_shipping}"
end
```